# SSDT network service account AdventureWorks DB

Tags: sql-server, ssas, business-intelligence, sql-server-data-tools

Recently, I have deployed the sample version of Adventure Works 2014 Multidimensional-EE using SQL Server Data Tools.The initial deployment did not cause any troubles, however I haven't been able to create any mining structures since then due to the following error:

```
OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error: Login failed for user 'XYZ8'.; 28000.
```

In SSDT, the impersonation information is set to: Service Account
Nonetheless, what is interesting is that SSMS displays "Default" Instead:
       [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyvg2.png)

Any help would be appreciated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the permissions on the service account?

There is an article on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175677.aspx) describing the required permissions.  I've taken the following extract:

> Granting permission to
>   read database metadata also grants permission to read the metadata of
>   all objects in the database. We suggest that you include the Read
>   Definition permission at the database level whenever you are setting
>   up roles for dedicated processing. Having Read Definition allows
>   non-administrators to view a model's object hierarchy in SQL Server
>   Management Studio and navigate to individual objects for subsequent
>   processing. In SQL Server Management Studio, connect to the instance
>   of Analysis Services, expand Roles for the appropriate database in
>   Object Explorer, and then click a database role (or create a new
>   database role). On the General tab, select the Read Definition option.
>   In the Membership pane, enter the Windows user and group accounts that
>   connect to Analysis Services using this role. Click OK to finish
>   creating the role.